# Check if operator $A$ is an observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, observables

Given operator $A$ and following relationships:
$A|2\rangle=|1\rangle+|3\rangle$ and 
$A|1\rangle=A|3\rangle=|2\rangle$.

I know that this operator should be self adjoint to correspond to an observable but how exactly do I show that?

Comment: Hint: Presumably, you are supposed to assume that the given basis is orthonormal.

Comment: I've edited your post to put more of it in latex.  For future ref, the commands you want are \rangle, or \langle for $\rangle$ and $\langle$, to make nice kets.

Comment: Before going into elegant proofs, have you written these 3 equations into 3x3 matrix form? is this matrix symmetric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $\{\vert 1\rangle, \vert 2\rangle,\vert 3\rangle\}$ form an orthonormal basis, systematically construct $\langle k\vert A\vert m\rangle$ to obtain
$$
\hat A\mapsto \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1 &0 \\
1&0& 1\\
0&1& 0\end{array}\right)
$$
and recall that in finite dimensions, there is no difference between hermitian and self-adjoint, and all eigenstates are normalizable.